# Splitting a string using ':' delimiter(python)

Tags: python, string, list, split

I am a novice at Python.

i am trying to split a string as follows using the ':' delimiter:

Example:

```
my_string = a/bc/rsd: Mar 4 10:13:23.78 : asgehaa:10/251[162]:%bavst{142}
new_list = my_string.split(":")
```

This should give out a list like this:

```
new_list = ['a/bc/rsd','Mar 4 10:13:23.78','asgehaa','10/251[162]','%bavst{142}']
```

Instead it splits also the date , and the resulting list looks like this:

```
new_list = ['a/bc/rsd','Mar 4 10','13','23.78','asgehaa','10/251[162]','%bavst{142}']
```

I dont want to split the date. Can i know a workaround to implement this?

Comment: What makes you think that Python should be able to guess _which_ colons you want to split on?

Comment: Indeed, the colons in the time are just as colony as any other colons in the string.

Comment: It splits on every `:`. How else should it work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question lacks minimal research or attempt to understand the language's behavior.

Comment: Please copy your code as it is. The first line is not valid Python syntax, for example.

Comment: Split on `': '` to get 3 parts, with the date intact, then split the last part on `':'`, so `s.split(': ')[:2] + s.split(': ')[2].split(':')`

Answer (score 4):

To follow the comments, it is unclear how are you going to let Python know where to use `:` as a delimiter and where to keep it. One option, *depending on the actual input data* you have, may be to use `re.split()` to split the string by `:` which has a *non-digit preceding character*:

```
>>> re.split(r"(?<!\d):", my_string)
['a/bc/rsd', ' Mar 4 10:13:23.78 ', ' asgehaa', '10/251[162]', '%bavst{142}']
```

where `(?<!\d)` is a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - looking for a previous character not to be a digit.

Comment: @cricket_007 I think I fixed that. Though this looks like a castle made of sand to me :)